# Dynamically adding to page model in form using Razor partial view

Tags: .net, post, razor, dynamic, partial-views

I created a Razor page that allowed the user to dynamically add to the object model before submitting form but when I tried to convert to a partial view the objects were not being added to the page model. Shouldn't the same code work when just moved to a partial view?

This code works:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddQuestion" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Question" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SurveyObject.Questions.Count; i++)
            {
                <h4><span class="alert-info">Question ID# @Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i].QuestionId</span></h4>
                <span class="hidden">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i].QuestionId)
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i].QuestionId)
                </span>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i].Question)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i].Question)
            }
    </div>
</div>
```

But when converted to a partial view it does not work:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="AddQuestion" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Question" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SurveyObject.Questions.Count; i++)
        {
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_SurveyCreateQuestion", Model.SurveyObject.Questions[i]);
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the supporting objects.

```
public class Survey
{
    public string SurveyName { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
    public Survey()
    {
        this.SurveyName = "new survey name here";
        this.Questions = new List<SurveyQuestion>();
    }
}
public class SurveyQuestion
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyResponse> ResponseList { get; set; }
    public SurveyQuestion() { }
    public SurveyQuestion(int id)
    {
        this.QuestionId = id;
        this.Question = "question text for id " + id;
        this.ResponseList = new List<SurveyResponse>();
    }
}
public class SurveyResponse
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public SurveyQuestion NextQuestion { get; set; }
    public SurveyResponse() { }
    public SurveyResponse(int id)
    {
        this.ResponseId = id;
        this.Response = "response text for id " + id;
    }
}
```

And here is the cshml file.

```
public class SurveyCreateModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Survey SurveyObject { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public void OnPostAddQuestion()
    {
        this.SurveyObject.Questions.Add(new SurveyQuestion(this.SurveyObject.Questions.Count + 1));
    }
}
```

And the partial view.

```
@model SurveyCreateModel.SurveyQuestion
@if (Model == null)
{
    <span></span>
}
else
{
    <h4><span class="alert-info">Question ID# @Model.QuestionId</span></h4>
    <span class="hidden">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.QuestionId)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.QuestionId)
    </span>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Question)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Question)
}
```

Looking at the source of the rendered HTML the loop without a partial view is creating unique elements as expected like these labels generated when the add question button is clicked twice.

```
<label for="SurveyObject_Questions_0__QuestionId">QuestionId</label>
<label for="SurveyObject_Questions_1__QuestionId">QuestionId</label>
```

But when the same code to generate the tags is moved into a partial view inside the same loop the html is rendered like this:

```
<label for="QuestionId">QuestionId</label>
```

Screen print of partial view not working - keep pressing add question but always stays at first question - model not updating

[image: notwork]

Screen print of code working - press add question button twice and two questions added - model is updating

[image: working]

Comment: please specify where is the problem - the partial view is not rendered or input-data is not posted to server side?

Comment: Added screen prints to show add question working and not working.

Comment: Also added rendered html of both working and non-working results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this to work with a partial view but it does work when using an editor template.

```
@model SurveyCreateModel.SurveyQuestion
<h4><span class="alert-info">Question ID# @Model.QuestionId</span></h4>
<span class="hidden">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.QuestionId)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.QuestionId)
</span>
@Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Question)
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Question)
```

Then this code was simply referenced by this in the cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SurveyObject.Questions)
</div>
```